# Cloud Variables not being set using Nerdbank.GitVersioning with Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, versioning, gitlab-ci

I'm using the Nuget package Nerdbank.GitVersioning to version my C# .Net DLL project and it is all working for local builds (tried within VS2017).

However when I try with the Gitlab runner to obtain the version number for use during my Nuget packaging steps none of the environment variables have been set regardless of what I have in my version.json file and/or using the nbgv cloud tool

My version.json file looks like this and is in the root of the repo;

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AArnott/Nerdbank.GitVersioning/master/src/NerdBank.GitVersioning/version.schema.json",
  "version": "2.0",
  "cloudBuild": {
    "setVersionVariables": true,
    "setAllVariables": true,
    "buildNumber": {
      "enabled": false,
      "includeCommitId": {
        "when": "nonPublicReleaseOnly",
        "where": "buildMetadata"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like this;

```
#Windows Configuration    

variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: "normal"
  URL: "https://localhost/repository/nuget-hosted"

before_script:
    - echo "Restoring nuget packages"
    - 'nuget restore MyProject.sln'
    #- echo "Installing NB.GV - GitVersioning Tool"
    - dotnet tool install --tool-path . nbgv


vs-15-2017-release-develop-build:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Building in Release mode"
    - 'msbuild my-project.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:PublicRelease=true'
    - echo "Testing in Release mode"
    - 'VSTest.Console.exe build/Release/MyProject.Test/MyProject.Test.dll'
    - echo "deploying build to internal nuget"
    - .\nbgv cloud
    - set #output all env variables for debug
    - nuget pack build/Release/MyProject/MyProject.nuspec -Version %BuildVersion% -Verbosity detailed
    - nuget push MyProject.%VERSION%.nupkg -source %URL% -apikey [removed]
  tags:
    - vs-15-2017
```

I've tried various different combinations of setting the cloudBuild parameters but nothing ever outputs the variables to the environment.

A secondary issue (and may be related) is that setting

> buildNumber.enabled = true

does not update the Gitlab build/job number too.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Cheers

Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nerdbank.GitVersioning doesn't have an implementation for GitLab CI that can set the cloud build number. [It can](https://github.com/AArnott/Nerdbank.GitVersioning/blob/master/src/NerdBank.GitVersioning/CloudBuildServices/GitLab.cs) recognize when running in GitLab CI, but has no code in the `SetCloudBuildNumber` method. Care to share a PR if you know how to make this work?

Comment: Hey thanks for confirming that. I had seen SetCloudBuildNumber was just returning an empty dictionary but hadn't dug too deep beyond that. :-)

Comment: Further investigation found that both my issues are down to no code in the implementation. I've submitted a pull request for a patch that will export the details as environment variables but haven't found a way to set the GitLab build number yet